# MIPS if greater or equals to

Tags: if-statement, assembly, mips

```
if ($t4 >= $5)
    $t8 = $t8+1
```

Given that pseudo-code, I put this attempt together based on various sources. Seems simple but i am still learning the foundations.  Not too sure if this is correct.

```
slt $t1, $t5, $t4
beq $t0, $zero, endLoop
addi $8, $8, 1
```

Main reference: [Greater than, less than equal, greater than equal in MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183346/greater-than-less-than-equal-greater-than-equal-in-mips)

Comment: does not make sense to me. RTM. Check for the typos.

Comment: In this case you can do it branchlessly, like `$t8 += ($t4 >= $t5)` adding the `slt` result instead of branching on it.  https://godbolt.org/z/E6eK1EaPf (That does also need an `xori` to invert the `slt` result, since its >= not just >.  See also [How can I do less than or equal in assembly language (MIPS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65974123))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some typos:

1. Your branch instruction is testing `$t0`, but the target of the `slt` is `$t1` so that is a mismatch.
2. You have a conditional branch instruction with a label, but don't define the label.
3. Your label name is `endLoop`, but this is *just* an `if`, not a `while` or other loop condition, and the the statement controlled by the `if` isn't a `break`.

Otherwise looks like you have the right idea.  *But this is tricky stuff to get right.*

To be clear, you are aware that we have to reverse (negate re: boolean logic) the sense of the condition for assembly language's if-goto style, as compared with structured programming's if-then construct.

```
if (t4 >= t5)
    t8++;
```

becomes

```
  if (t4 < t5) goto skip;  //  !(a >= b)  --->  a < b
  t8++;
skip: ;
```

Now, I would have written the above more directly in assembly:

```
  slt $t1, $t4 $t5       # let's see if t4 < t5
  bne $t1, $zero, skip   # yes? goto skip
  addi $t8,$t8,1
skip:
```

Instead you have reversed the operands `$t4` and `$t5`, and then also reversed the branch condition: `beq` vs. my `bne`.  This is very close to a triple negation of the (structured style) C (and this would have worked), but there is a subtle difference.

So, what you have written is:

```
  if (!(t5 < t4)) goto skip;
  t8++;
skip: ;
```

which — translated to structure programming — is:

```
if (t5 < t4)      // logically: remove the negation and incorporate then
    t8++;
```

and we can see that if we reverse the operands but also switch the relation, we have:

```
if (t4 > t5)      // same exact logical condition as immediately above
    t8++;
```

So, your code does not produce the same condition test as the C code, since the operation under equality is different from the original.

You assembly code is doing `t4 > t5`, and the C code is doing `t4 >= t5`.  See the difference?

---

This stuff is tricky because:

1. We have to reverse (negate) the condition when going between structured statement and if-goto style, and,
2. MIPS provides only one of the ordered relational operations (it has `<` but not `<=`, `>`, `>=`), and so, that means when we need what would have been `sge` we have to simulate it (via `slt` by reversing operands and/or reversing the branch on true vs. branch false).

---

Related:

- [Mutiple conditions in if in MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375267/mutiple-conditions-in-if-in-mips) - `if( x<y && x<z )` or similar.  One way is to compare into booleans and AND or OR them together, instead of short-circuiting by doing multiple branches.
- [How can I implement if(condition1 && condition2) in MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408890/how-can-i-implement-ifcondition1-condition2-in-mips) - `if (x < 10 && x > 5)` or similar: with two branches, or with the range-check trick.
- [How to do less than or equal in Assembly Language(MIPS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736836/how-to-do-less-than-or-equal-in-assembly-languagemips) - compare into boolean integer for conditions other than `slt`